# Errors shown in Eclipse Editor when using certain servlet classes

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

My Eclipse editor complains about certain classes in servlet API. Only some of them.

For example, *"The import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream cannot be resolved"*

[image: import not resolved]

note that the rest of servlet classes and imports are correctly resolved.

Also, the Eclipse Editor Windows shows another two spurioius errors in the code: *"ServletOutputStream cannot be resolved to a type"* and *"The type javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher is not visible"*.

[image: code errors]

I have checked that the Tomcat 9 `servlet-api.jar` is included in the build path.

[image: build path contains servlet api]

and I made sure that checking and unchecking in Order and Export does not make any difference.

[image: build path order does not affect]

what I can do to solve this annoyance?

Note also that it's just an annoyance. The code compiles. It gets deployed. And runs perfectly in tomcat.

Comment: Can you also show us the "Order and Export" tab? I think I vaguely recall you have to check the checkbox next to it on that tab. (Haven't worked with eclipse for a while now...)

Comment: just tried out, checking and unchecking "Tomcat" makes no difference, the offending lines are still being highlighted in the editor. I have updated the question with this info.